# Zero supported devices results on google play store

Tags: android, google-play

My manifest:

> android:versionName="1.0" >

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android:glEsVersion=&quot;0x00020000&quot;"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
```

on GooglePlayStore i get zero Supported devices..
what the problem?

Comment: This one <uses-feature
    android:name="android:glEsVersion=&quot;0x00020000&quot;"
    android:required="true" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the requirement of a feature, that does not exist:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android:glEsVersion=&quot;0x00020000&quot;"
    android:required="true" />
```

What you most likely want is:

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change glEsVersion to:

```
 <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```