# Google Play - 0 Supported Devices Issue

Tags: android, google-play

Can anyone help me to solve **Google Play - Zero Supported Devices**  issue. Below is the my AndroidManifest file.

[image]

-->

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>


<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

I have tried below options

[Google Play - Zero Supported Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589061/google-play-zero-supported-devices)

[Zero supported devices results on google play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044598/zero-supported-devices-results-on-google-play-store?rq=1)

build.gradle file structure is as below,

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
        mavenCentral()

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply from: '../config/quality.gradle'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}



def versionMajor = 0
def appVersionCode
def versionMinor
def versionDate = "${buildTime()}"

def buildTime() {
    return new Date().format("YYMMdd", TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
}

def versionPropsFile = file('../config/quality/version.properties')


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    /*if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
        def value = 0
        def runTasks = gradle.startParameter.taskNames
        logger.info('Value Code  - ' + runTasks)
        if ('assemble' in runTasks || 'assembleRelease' in runTasks || 'aR' in runTasks) {
            value = 1;
        }
        logger.info('Value Code  - ' + value)

        appVersionCode = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger() + value
        versionMinor = versionProps['DAY_COUNT'].toInteger()
        def buildDate = versionProps['DATE'].toString()
        if (buildDate != versionDate) {
            versionMinor = 1
        } else {
            versionMinor = versionMinor + 1;
        }

        versionProps['VERSION_CODE'] = appVersionCode.toString()
        versionProps['DAY_COUNT'] = versionMinor.toString()
        versionProps['DATE'] = versionDate.toString()
        versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)


    } else {
        throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }*/

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myappe"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 11
        versionName "4.0"
    }

    aaptOptions {
        useNewCruncher true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("../config/keystore/myapp_app.jks")
            storePassword "myappapp"
            keyAlias "myappApp"
            keyPassword "myappapp"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            testCoverageEnabled false
        }
        debug {

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            testCoverageEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':myapplibrary')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.1@aar'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.androidmapsextensions:android-maps-extensions:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: can you show your build.gradle?

Comment: @ligi please check edited question.

Comment: just did - but you seem to have another problem - thought it might be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22730620/bad-apk-when-using-bitcoinj-from-maven-central

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - 0 devices supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044686/android-0-devices-supported)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Google bug :(

I have verified this for 4-5 apps.

Bug Description :

Whenever new version of app is publishing on Android play store and once APK is uploaded then in APK description it always show **Supported Android Devices** count **0 Devices**. [image]